# How to pass images in loop bootstrap carousel in angular ? i am trying with *ng for but it ended appearing only first image in array

Tags: angular

i want to pass images from array to carousel, i am trying with approach with *ngFor but it is showing only first image in array.
i want it in loop always.

```
Below is my .html code

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover" data-wrap="true" data-interval="2000"  >
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" style="height:330px;" >
      <div class="item" *ngFor="let cImg of maincorousel">
        <img src="{{cImg.cakeImgAdd}}" id="{{cId[1]}}" alt="Los Angeles"(click)="onSelectCake($event)" 
           style=" 
          width: 100%;">
      </div>    
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" onclick=""></span>
      <span class="sr-only" >Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>



**My .ts file from where i am passing the images**


mainCorousel:mainCorouselCakesModel[] =[
    new mainCorouselCakesModel(1,"assets/rollin-images/mainCorousel1.jpg","ChocoLava","As Soft as cloud")
  ];
```